# How to replace HTML Tags using Javascript or JQuery without any Class name or ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, innerhtml, appendchild, outerhtml

Please help me replacing below html code

**Original Code**

```
<div class="multiAttType">
    <input type="radio" id="Radio7_1" value="Google">
    <label for="Radio7_1" class="radioChoice">Google</label>
</div>

<div class="multiAttType">
    <input type="radio" id="Radio7_2" value="Bing">
    <label for="Radio7_2" class="radioChoice">Bing</label>
</div>
```

**On PageLoad It Should Be Changed To**

```
<div class="multiAttType">
    <input type="radio" id="Radio7_1" value="Google">
    <span class="sameclass">Google <a href="https://www.google.com/">Link 1</a></span>
</div>

<div class="multiAttType">
    <input type="radio" id="Radio7_2" value="Bing">
    <span class="sameclass">Bing <a href="https://www.bing.com/">Link 2</a></span>
</div>
```

Comment: do you want to replace this in runtime?

Comment: Yes, one page load

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using :contains() selector in jquery.

Example : $('label:contains("Google")')

Now use replaceWith function from jquery to replace the html content.

Updated the code snippet to replace the html content on page load.

```js
function replaceHtml(){

$('label:contains("Google")').replaceWith('<span class="sameclass">Google <a href="https://www.google.com/">Link 1</a></span>')

$('label:contains("Bing")').replaceWith('<span class="sameclass">Bing <a href="https://www.bing.com/">Link 2</a></span>')

}


$(document).ready(function(){

//calling the replace function on page load
replaceHtml();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="multiAttType">
    <input type="radio" id="Radio7_1" value="Google">
    <label for="Radio7_1" class="radioChoice">Google</label>
</div>

<div class="multiAttType">
    <input type="radio" id="Radio7_2" value="Bing">
    <label for="Radio7_2" class="radioChoice">Bing</label>
</div>


<button onclick="replaceHtml()">Replace</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a static way

```js
window.onload = function() {
 var multAtt = document.getElementsByClassName('multiAttType');
  
  for (var i = 0; i < multAtt.length; i++) {
  
   var children = multAtt[i].children;
    
    for (var j = 0; j < children.length; j++) {
       
      if(children[j].innerHTML == 'Google' && children[j].tagName == 'LABEL') {
        multAtt[i].removeChild(multAtt[i].children[j]);
        multAtt[i].insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<span class="sameclass">Google <a href="https://www.google.com/">Link 1</a></span>');
      } else if ( children[j].innerHTML == 'Bing' && children[j].tagName == 'LABEL') {
    multAtt[i].removeChild(multAtt[i].children[j]);
        multAtt[i].insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<span class="sameclass">Bing <a href="https://www.bing.com/">Link 2</a></span>');
      }
      
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="multiAttType">
  <input type="radio" id="Radio7_1" value="Google">
  <label for="Radio7_1" class="radioChoice">Google</label>
</div>

<div class="multiAttType">
  <input type="radio" id="Radio7_2" value="Bing">
  <label for="Radio7_2" class="radioChoice">Bing</label>
</div>
```